# Emscripten: Offer to download/save a generated MEMFS file

Tags: c++, emscripten

I am playing with emscripten for fun, and compiled an old simulator program of mine to run in-browser.

The program saves the output as a data file and, since I did nothing special, it should reside on MEMFS (memory file system).

How do I allow the user to download the resulting file from MEMFS? Can I trigger the browser's regular save-file dialog?

Answer (score 6):

Got it:

- Add FS to EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS during compilation.

```
$ emcc --bind -std=c++11 \
       -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=FS \
       -o main.js *.cpp
```

- Add the function below to you .html or .js files.

```
function offerFileAsDownload(filename, mime) {
  mime = mime || "application/octet-stream";

  let content = Module.FS.readFile(filename);
  console.log(`Offering download of "${filename}", with ${content.length} bytes...`);

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = filename;
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content], {type: mime}));
  a.style.display = 'none';

  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
  }, 2000);
}
```

- Call the funtion (OPTION 1) on postRun:

```
<script>
// This must go BEFORE sourcing main.js:
var Module = {
  onRuntimeInitialized: () => {
    Module.postRun.push(() => offerFileAsDownload("filename.ext", "mime/type"));
  }
};
</script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

- Call the function (OPTION 2) at the end of the C++ code:

```
int main() {
  // ...
  emscripten::val::global("window").call<void>(
    "offerFileAsDownload",
    string("filename.ext"),
    string("mime/type")
  );
  // ...
}
```

Comment: One also needs to include emscripten/bind.h for option 2.

Answer (score -1):

I have published a small header-only C++ library that allows file download and upload in Emscripten:

https://github.com/Armchair-Software/emscripten-browser-file

This can be done much more simply than the other answer, using just `EM_JS` - the following example is from the above:

```cpp
EM_JS(void, download, (char const *filename, char const *mime_type, void const *buffer, size_t buffer_size), {
  /// Offer a buffer in memory as a file to download, specifying download filename and mime type
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = UTF8ToString(filename);
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, buffer, buffer_size)], {type: UTF8ToString(mime_type)}));
  a.click();
});
```

This works with any memory buffer, - if you want to reference MEMFS specifically, you can use `Module.FS.readFile(filename)`.